# issue with spark sql functions?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to get the maximum product price from the data.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as func
from pyspark.sql import Row
rdd=sc.textFile("/mnt/my_s3_data/retail_db/products/").map(lambda x: x.split(','))
row_rdd=rdd.map(lambda o : Row(product_id=o[0],product_category_id=o[1],product_name=o[2],product_description=o[3],product_price=o[4],product_image=o[5]))
df=row_rdd.toDF()
df.select(func.max('product_price')).show()
```

**Result** :
 999.99

**Expected** **Result** :
1999.99

```
df.where(func.col('product_id') == 208).show()
```

output :
  I'm getting the product price 1999.99

Note :
** If I limit the dataframe till 255 records i'm getting the expected output :

```
df.limit(255).agg({"product_price": "max"}).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because product_id  is of **string** type the max function will do string comparison to find max value not number comparison so you got the wrong result, to avoid  this you need to cast the type to number

Below is the sample code

```
    val updatedDF= df.withColumn("product_id_num",expr("cast (product_id as 
    double)")).withColumnRenamed("product_id_num","product_id")
```

now find the max on updatedDf you will get the accurate result.

Comment: I converted the type to double and tried to find the max() but i'm getting ValueError: could not convert string to float: .

Comment: may be product_id contains some string values, normally in scala those kind of values will be converted to null and max will ignore them

Comment: I'm trying it in python. One more clarification if try df.where("product_id" > some_number) i'm getting TypeError: condition should be string or Column. but as per spark documentation we can access the column using "column_name" rite ?

Answer (score 0):

It is working

> newDF = df.filter("product_price != ''")
>   newDF.select(func.max(newDF.product_price.cast("double")).alias('maximum_price')).show()